# Issue while Authenticating user with Active Directory (using AD domain) using Spring Security from Spring-boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate the users from Active Directory by using

```
org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider
```

**CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("companyDomain", "ldap://companyDomain:389", "rootDN");

    activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setSearchFilter("(userPrincipalName={0})");
    activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(customUserDetailsContextMapper);
    authentication = activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    return authentication;
}
```

When I use IP in the url (***ldap://x.x.x.x:389***), authentication with AD is successful. But when I use domain in ldap url (***ldap://companyDomain:389***), code throws below exception

```
2018-05-16 22:57:23.711 ERROR 11552 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception

org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: companyDomain:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: companyDomain:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
        at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:108) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:212) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.herbalife.training.security.CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:180) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: companyDomain:389
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:137) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1615) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2749) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider$ContextFactory.createContext(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:402) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:203) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        ... 74 common frames omitted
```

My requirement is to connect to AD and authenticate user by using AD domain.
Java/Spring allows me to do the same using IP but not domain.

Answer (score 0):

It could be DNS issue, can you run dig command and check whether it resolves the ipaddress

```
dig companyDomain
```